# Image/div is too big

Tags: html, css

This image is too big, I want it to fit the size of the window: http://zgaming.comxa.com

but I do not understand how, I also tried height and width 100%

html

```
<div class="bgimg"><img src="http://zgaming.comxa.com/dist/img/bg.jpg"></img></div>
```

css

```
    .bgimg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-99;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}
```

I also tried this

```
.bgimg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:-99;

}

.imgbg {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43612299/7874902

works but on mobile there is some white space at the bottom..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't use `background-size: cover` on a img tag.

Just try to make `background-image` with yours and make div size at 100% on width and height.

You can make this rule directly on body :

```
body {
    background: url(./path_to_your_image) center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url('http://zgaming.comxa.com/dist/img/bg.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html{
height: 100%
}
```

Comment: What's _"a image children?"_ Your wording isn't clear.

Comment: children image is like : div > img

Comment: LMAO i didnt say that, the div has children ! And the children is an image... @Andrei check my new code, directly on body works fine

Comment: Probably should have said, _"you can't use `background-size: cover` with an `img` tag."_ That would have been a lot clearer. And yes, the way you originally worded it does suggest the div has children.

Comment: Can we see what have you completed on url background image path please ?

Comment: @Andrei you have this rule in another css : .login-page, .register-page {
    background: #d2d6de;
} it's rewrite background and background-size, just delete them or make !important after eache property (http://zgaming.comxa.com/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css)

Comment: @Andrei you should use a class or CSS selector with higher specificity over using `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set

```
background-image: url("http://zgaming.comxa.com/dist/img/bg.jpg");
```

and try with

```
background size: contain;
```

as with cover it's possible it cuts a part of the image.
check this:
[w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code spinet help you.

```css
.bgimg {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bgimg img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimg"><img src="http://zgaming.comxa.com/dist/img/bg.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should describe what you're doing and why it works to provide some quality to this answer.

Comment: Thank you alot but if you can also explain why this works.. ? :D

Comment: Uh, on mobile it doesn't fit the whole page, there is some white at the bottom

Comment: just setting height and width of the image 100%. It acquired browser window width and height.

Comment: Yes, if you have a window vertical, more height than width, it's ugly, just check your code before post

Comment: @hungerstar My code is working, i make solution for him in comments, he have a rules rewriting in another css so my code works fine, this code works, but it's not the function required. So make a -1 is very stupid for a working code...

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman your code doesn't work if someone else comes along and doesn't realize (or bother) to follow the link to his site to see that there's additional CSS on his site that helps make your answer work. On it's own, your answer does not work. Someone probably down voted you because if you were to copy and paste your answer into a Stack Snippet or a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vgwqchef/) it wouldn't work.

Comment: @hungerstar Because snippet or jsfiddle the body is empty so html too, just look my snippet or make html height 100% on your fiddle ...

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman exactly. Glad you filled in the missing piece. P.S. `body` is already 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is purely meant to only show how to try and fill the viewport with a single image, no extras.

We use `min-height: 100vh` to tell the `body` tag to be as tall as the viewport. we use `background-size: cover` to center the image an have it fill all of the `body` element, cropping if necessary but maintaining aspect ratio.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url( 'http://zgaming.comxa.com/dist/img/bg.jpg' );
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

There's one major thing you have to realize with trying to fill a viewport, especially viewports with varying aspect ratios; you'll either have to crop part of the image at some point or distort it. Below we chose to crop it over distorting it.